# Alias for "echo $?" doesn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I am trying to set alias for `echo $?` which returns exit status of the most recently executed command. I've put `alias status="echo $?"` in `~/.bashrc`. But it's not working, it's always returning 0.

```
user@host:~$ lll
bash: lll: command not found
user@host:~$ echo $?
127
user@host:~$ lll
bash: lll: command not found
user@host:~$ status
0
user@host:~$
```

How to set alias for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes to prevent the shell from replacing the `$?` when defining the alias:

```
alias status='echo $?'
```